# Tables in a row or table and image in a row in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I know how to put images in a row when exporting org-mode to html:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: style="display:inline;"
[[image1.png]]
#+ATTR_HTML: style="display:inline;"
[[image2.png]]
```

which will make this effect:

```
Image 1 Image 2
```

What if I want two **tables** in a row, or **one table and one image** in a row, like:

```
Table 1   Table 2
```

or

```
Image 1 Table 1
```

What shall I do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works by floating the 2 tables to the left:

```
#+attr_html: style="float:left;width:30%;margin:3ex;"
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

#+attr_html: style="float:left;width:30%;margin:3ex"
| 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 |

#+html: <br style="clear:both;" />
This goes beneath
```

The `clear` attribute is needed in order to continue below the 2 floated elements.

Comment: For newer versions of org-mode, you would use lines like `#+ATTR_HTML: :style float:left;width:30%;margin:3ex` instead of the format given above.